# Creating Simple Database in MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby, database

all, I'm new to using MySQL and I'm having some issues creating a simple database for uploading a basic ruby app. Can anybody help me with the format to use in the MySQL Command? I'm using MySQL 5.5.

I have searched online; however, all of the typical formats for creating a database seem to have no result at all on prompt - should I be seeing some sort of visual confirmation that a database was created? Thanks, all!

Comment: What have you tried? What hasn't worked? What error messages are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

As a new user I would highly recommend trying out phpMyAdmin as an interface to MySQL.  I know it's not ruby, but if you have php setup already anyways it's a very useful tool.

http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php

With this tool, you can create a database with the click of a single button, run SQL commands, create tables and set permissions.

Comment: +1 phpMyAdmin is the way to go. Provides a nice UI to view the tables. What I used for my first MySQL project.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `DESCRIBE tablename` where `tablename` is the name of a table you think you have created. That way you can check whether it was created or not.

Answer (score 0):

The command for creating a database is `CREATE DATABASE database_name;`. Don't forget the semicolon at the end.

If it's successful you should see a message like `Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)`. Any query should have at east this much output. If you see no message at all (e.g. you press enter and the next line just looks like a `->` prompt) make sure you've closed all of your parentheses and quotation mark and ended the query with a semicolon (`;`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MySQL informs you of the result of each query. Here's what I've just got:

> mysql> create database foo;
>
> Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
>
> mysql> use foo;
>
> Database changed
>
> mysql> show tables;
>
> Empty set (0.00 sec)
>
> mysql>

If you need visual feedback, please consider downloading [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html) - it is easy to use and, as a GUI application, is explicit enough to make a new user feel comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

When you issue the following command at the mysql prompt:

```
CREATE database <database_name>;
```

You should be presented with the typical "Ok" prompt afterwards. You should then be able to do :

```
show databases;
```

That will show you a list of databases on the system and in there you should see the database you created.